# How we can handle multiple tabs in Cypress?

Tags: windows, tabs, cypress

I have a scenario in my application in which when user click on button, it opens the 2 tabs and I have to go to the both tabs and verify the content in Cypress.

I want to handle the both window tabs and verify the content.

Comment: See also [Not able to switch to a new tab or window using cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72740201/not-able-to-switch-to-a-new-tab-or-window-using-cypress).